# Partitions of ${\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ induced by convergent, but not absolutely convergent series

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, group-actions

Let $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence such that the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, but does not converge absolutely.
Then there is a partition of the symmetric group ${\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ into

- sets $S_x \ (x \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\})$ of all
  $\sigma \in {\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ for which the series
  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n^\sigma}$ converges to $x$, and
- a set $S_{\rm NaN}$ of all $\sigma \in {\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ for which
  the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n^\sigma}$ does not converge.

**Question:** Has there any work been done on properties of this partition
for particular series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

Basic observations are:

- all sets in the partition have the same cardinality, and
- all sets in the partition are closed under multiplication from the right
  by permutations $\sigma$ which satisfy the condition
  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ |n - n^\sigma| \leq C$ for some constant $C$.

**Added on Oct 11, 2014:** Let the *spectrum* $\mathcal{S}_{\sum a_n}(G)$
of a group $G < {\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ with respect to the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be the set of all
$x \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty,{\rm NaN}\}$ such that
$G \cap S_x \neq \emptyset$. --

- Is it true that if $G$ has *full spectrum* with respect to a series
  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ (i.e. $\mathcal{S}_{\sum a_n}(G) = \mathbb{R}
      \cup \{-\infty,+\infty,{\rm NaN}\}$), then $G$ has full spectrum
  also with respect to any other conditionally convergent series
  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$?
- Are there countable groups whose spectrum with respect to a particular
  series is dense in $\mathbb{R}$? -- And if yes, does the choice of the
  series actually matter here?

Comment: All sets in the partition indeed have the same cardinality, but don't we also know that $|S_x|=|{\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})|=|\mathbb R|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty,{\rm NaN}\}$?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Yes, of course.

Comment: Have you see this paper? "Rearrangement of conditionally convergent series on a small set", by Rafał Filipów, and Piotr Szuca. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 362 (2010) 64–71. It is not exactly the same question, but some of the information there appears relevant.

Comment: Is $S_{\sum a_n}$ a subgroup?  If we generalize the definition of spectrum to apply to arbitrary subsets of $\rm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$, then a more general question is: Is it true that for any conditionally convergent $\sum b_n$, $\left|\mathcal{S}_{\sum b_n}\left(S_{\sum a_n}\right)\right| = 1$?

Comment: @Andres: Thank you for this reference!

Comment: @StefanKohl you misread my comment.  The first question is about $S_{\sum a_n}$, i.e. $S_x$ where $x = \sum a_n$, the value that the series conditionally converges to.  It's a regular $S$, not a script $\mathcal{S}$, and there's no $G$ being mentioned.

Comment: @StefanKohl in my second question, first I consider generalizing the notion of spectrum to apply to any subset of the symmetric group, not just subgroups, i.e. for any $X \subset \rm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$, consider $\mathcal{S}_{\sum a_n}(X)$.  I ask, if $X$ has spectrum of size 1 with respect to one conditionally convergent series, does it have spectrum of size 1 with respect to all such series?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta: Sorry, you are right -- I just misread the $S$ for an $\mathcal{S}$. I removed my previous comment.

Comment: Not that it helps much but it seems more natural to quotient everything by the subgroup of finite permutations as they do not affect the whole setup in any way.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, of course one can take everything modulo the finitary symmetric group. In fact it holds even more -- namely, $\sigma \in S_x$ implies $\sigma' \in S_x$ if $\tau := \sigma/\sigma'$ satisfies $|n^\tau-n| < c$ for some constant $c$ and all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that if $G$ has full spectrum with respect to a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ then $G$ has full spectrum also with respect to any other conditionally convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$?

If I understand the definitions correctly, clearly no. Let $G$ be the symmetric group of $2\mathbb{N}$ and consider conditionally convergent series supported on the evens or odds.

> Are there countable groups whose spectrum with respect to a particular series is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Sure. Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be a conditionally convergent series. For a countable dense set of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, pick $\sigma_x \in \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ so that the rearrangement by $\sigma_x$ is $x$. Let $G$ be the group generated by the $\sigma_x$.

> And if yes, does the choice of the series actually matter here?

Another evens/odds example comes to mind...